# How to do sonar job separately in jenkins for maven 3 project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am configuring sonar plug-in in Jenkins to execute on Maven 3 projects.

Currently my maven project is scheduled to build when a code change in svn and also for every 2hrs

Now I want to run the sonar on the same project only once in the night time, this should not impact the regular builds.

I installed Jenkins Sonar Plugin and could able to add the sonar in the 'Post Build Actions' of the project configuration, and the everything build fine. But in this case the sonar is running each time after the project build is done, I want to run the sonar only at the night time.

In my approach I did not included sonar maven plugin in pom file, since I want to use Jenkins sonar plugin

Please let me know what changes I need to do from pom end and Jenkins end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest solution is definitely to create a dedicated Jenkins Job to schedule those SonarQube analysis. Some users are also using the trigger configuration "Skip if environment variable is defined and set to true" to reach such goal.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Freddy. I am new to Jenkins as well, can you please explain me how to create a dedicated Jenkins Job!

Comment: See the Jenkins documentation : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Use+Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to install sonar plugin in your pom file. sonar plugin for jenkins does the job.all you have to do is for every project create two different jobs in jenkins .

- one job is to trigger automated build whenever there is svn checkin (you can configure it for every 2 hrs as you said)

-another job is to run sonar analysis for the project and you can configure it to run every midnight. ( you can give like ' @midnight ')